# iOS - How to delay of showing message "purchase was successful" to wait until the validation receipt finished

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, receipt-validation

i've searched and can't find any way to create a delay of showing message: "Your purchase was successful" to wait until the validation receipt finished.

I've tried to quote the line `SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)` but the message still fires.

```
 func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        print("Received Payment Transaction Response from Apple");

        for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
            if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{
                switch trans.transactionState {
                case .Purchased:
                    print("Product Purchased");
                    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)

                    // validate receipt and update money
                    validateReceipt(trans.payment.productIdentifier)

                    break;
                case .Failed:
                    print("Purchased Failed");
                    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)

                    self.indicator.Hide()
                    break;
                case .Restored:
                    print("restored")
                    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                    //[self restoreTransaction:transaction];

                    self.indicator.Hide()
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically there is no way to delay the "purchase was successful" message.

But you can show an additional alert after validating the receipt, showing the results of validation to user.

Comment: Tks, i think so too, but no one confirms it.

Comment: Has anyone figured this out!? I too have implemented receipt validation and it confusing to get the You're all Set success message when the receipt validation comes back as fraudulent!? Is there anyway to suppress this message till after the validation of the receipt?

Comment: There is no such way. You have to rely on an extra message after validation to convey the final status to user.